# How to show multiple images one after another in imageview dynamically in android

Tags: android

Sir I am making an app in which i have an activity where I will enter any sentence in edit text box and my code will split it into characters and then I have to show images corresponding to each character one after another in same pattern by which sentence is composed of characters. Now i dont know which technique should I use. One of my senior said me to use multi threading but I dont know how to code it...can you give me some hint. Please. Its about my final project of MCS and we did not study android in our course work I am doing it on my own. Really need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your letters one after the other in the sense that the next letter would appear on the screen after previous disappears then you would need basic multithreading for that.

You need to make changes to the UI thread while you iterate over the letters of your sentence
in a different thread which can be put to sleep in each iteration.

Here's how you must go about it

Suppose, you get your string in the variable `str`

`String str="YourSentence";`

Create a new Thread that contains a loop to traverse your sentence.In each iteration of this loop update the ImageView on UI thread using `runOnUIthread()` and then put the thread to sleep

Here's how your thread body must look like

```
        Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

        for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            final int j=i;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    final Bitmap bmpLetter=MainActivity.this.getBitmapFromAsset(str.charAt(j)+".jpg");
                    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bmpLetter);
                }
                });
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        }
    };
```